# Bootstrap Post Carousel blocking other PHP in page-template

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a post carousel within a WordPress page-template, but all other PHP (such as Advanced Custom Fields content and such) get blocked. The wp_debug shows no errors and I can't find any error within the code.

Below is the code I have used to create the carousel with recent posts from a custom post type:

When I entirely remove the slider all PHP below it does work/load, but I can't seem to find a mistake in the code.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php
    $i = 2; 
    global $post; 
    $args = array( 
            'numberposts'       => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'work',
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    if($myposts):
          $chunks = array_chunk($myposts, $i);
          $html = "";
          foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
            ($chunk === reset($chunks)) ? $active = "active" : $active = "";
            $html .= '<div class="item '.$active.'">';
            foreach($chunk as $post) {
              $html .= '<div id="timeline-item" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><div><h6 style="text-align: left;">';
              $html .= get_the_date('Y');
              $html .= '</h6><h2 style="text-align: left;">';
              $html .= get_the_title();
              $html .= '</h2><p style="text-align: left;">';
              $html .= get_post_field('post_content');
              $html .= '</p></div></div>';
            };
            $html .= '</div>';                
            };
          echo $html;             
        endif;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean 'all other php' gets blocked? is there anything in your error_log?

Comment: For example <?php the_field('stalk-me'); ?> should display the content that you can add in the back-end, but instead it displays nothing at all. When I remove the entire slider the content is displayed.

Comment: hmm. do you have the full script there?

Comment: This is the entire page-template.php file: https://pastebin.com/EbbfxdSf

Comment: For bootstrap carousel, I've made it easy way. :)
https://prabinparajuli.com.np/add-bootstrap-carousel-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `$post`. In WordPress **never** override `$post`
Try replacing this part.

```
foreach($chunk as $slide) {
          $html .= '<div id="timeline-item" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><div><h6 style="text-align: left;">';
          $html .= get_the_date('Y', $slide);
          $html .= '</h6><h2 style="text-align: left;">';
          $html .= get_the_title($slide);
          $html .= '</h2><p style="text-align: left;">';
          $html .= get_post_field('post_content', $slide);
          $html .= '</p></div></div>';
        };
```

Not sure if this will solve the rest of the problems. It might.
And if it doesn't at least your code will be a bit cleaner.

**EDIT**
Seeing the full script this is very likely the problem.

line 109 `if( have_rows('skill-bars')` will take the wrong `$post` which you broke.

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed works.

I was not aware of the possible effects of overriding the $post, so lesson learned!

Comment: Also an option. Is to use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). And is instead of array_chunck use a [modulo](https://alvinalexander.com/php/php-modulus-operator-syntax-examples)